# SQL: Making a 'computation row'

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
TYPE | A | B | C | ... | Z
one  | 4 | 4 | 4 | ... | 4
two  | 3 | 2 | 2 | ... | 1
```

And I wanted to insert a row with a computation (row one minus row two):

```
TYPE | A | B | C | ... | Z
one  | 4 | 4 | 4 | ... | 4
two  | 3 | 2 | 2 | ... | 1
delta| 1 | 2 | 2 | ... | 3
```

I was thinking of a SQL command that looks like

```
(select A from table where type=one) - (select A from table where type=two)
```

Down side is, it's too long and I also have to do that for all the columns (A-Z) and that's quite a lot.

I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this.

PS:

The sequence of my code looks like this btw:

```
// I'm inserting the data from a RawTable to a TempTable

INSERT one
INSERT two
INSERT delta
INSERT three
INSERT four
INSERT delta
...
INSERT onehundredone
INSERT onehundredtwo
INSERT delta
```

Comment: Presumably, you don't want to store this data, just include it in a result set? Also, I think your numbering has gone off in `...`, since if you're working pairwise, `onehundredone` and `onehundredtwo` should be a pair.

Comment: i'm storing this to a temp table and then bind it to a gridview. yeah it should be 102, i just showed that to emphasize the number of rows.

Comment: Sounds like a UI issue to me... You could probably do it in SQL (you didn't mention which SQL product or version you're using), but it would likely work much better if you extended your data grid to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added an ID column with `identity` to your temp table. You can use that to figure out what rows should be grouped.

```
create table YourTable
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  [TYPE] varchar(20),
  A int,
  B int,
  C int
)

insert into YourTable ([TYPE], A, B, C)
select 'one',   4, 4, 4 union all
select 'two',   3, 2, 2 union all
select 'three', 7, 4, 4 union all
select 'four',  3, 2, 2 union all
select 'five',  8, 4, 4 union all
select 'six',   3, 2, 2


select T.[TYPE], T.A, T.B, T.C
from
  (
    select
      T.ID,
      T.[TYPE],
      T.A,
      T.B,
      T.C
    from YourTable as T  
    union all  
    select
      T2.ID,
      'delta' as [TYPE],
      T1.A-T2.A as A,
      T1.B-T2.B as B,
      T1.C-T2.C as C
    from YourTable as T1
      inner join YourTable as T2
        on T1.ID = T2.ID-1 and
           T2.ID % 2 = 0
  ) as T
order by T.ID, case T.[TYPE] when 'delta' then 1 else 0 end
```

Result:

```
TYPE                 A           B           C
-------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
one                  4           4           4
two                  3           2           2
delta                1           2           2
three                7           4           4
four                 3           2           2
delta                4           2           2
five                 8           4           4
six                  3           2           2
delta                5           2           2
```

Sorting on column C from first row in group:

```
select T.[TYPE], T.A, T.B, T.C
from
  (
    select
      T1.ID,
      T1.[TYPE],
      case T1.ID % 2 when 1 then T1.C else T2.C end as Sortorder,
      T1.A,
      T1.B,
      T1.C
    from YourTable as T1
      left outer join YourTable as T2
        on T1.ID = T2.ID+1  
    union all  
    select
      T2.ID,
      'delta' as [TYPE],
      T1.C as Sortorder,
      T1.A-T2.A as A,
      T1.B-T2.B as B,
      T1.C-T2.C as C
    from YourTable as T1
      inner join YourTable as T2
        on T1.ID = T2.ID-1 and
           T2.ID % 2 = 0
  ) as T
order by T.Sortorder, T.ID, case T.[TYPE] when 'delta' then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Plus one for getting it spot on!

Comment: can i ask you another question, is it possible to sort the groups `(one, two, delta)` according to the value of `column C` and `row 1` of that group?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this "easily" (i.e. without having to specify every column), I can't come up with any way to do it easily, so I'll go on the record as saying that it can't be done. Easily.

The non-easy way would be to build dynamic code--something that loops through the database metadata, builds a string containing the statement(s) to execute your desired routine column by column, and then execute that string. You really want to avoid this whenever possible.

One shortcut, if you just need to build a procedure or function that does this (i.e. build once run many), you could copy the list of columns into a spreadsheet (Excel), build out the highly-repetitive statements using forumlas that reference the column names, and then copying the results back. (This is much simpler to do than it is to explain.)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you're doing this, but the way I'd approach it is:

```
insert into table
select 'delta', 
t1.a - t2.a, 
t1.b - t2.b
.....
from table t1, 
table t2
where t1.type = 'one'
and t2.type = 'two'
```

You would have to run this query immediately after inserting "one" and "two", then re-run it after inserting "three" and "four". Nasty nasty nasty.

If you can re-name the columns in some way, or create a numerical column, you could run it in a single query.

Comment: it's because i have to show a report that looks like that. get pair from database and then show delta. and then do the same for the rest. so what im doing is storing it all in a temp table and then just bind that to a single gridview. or is there a better way?

Comment: Well, you could do it in the front end - but your solution sounds as reasonable as any other...you need to come up with a way of ordering the result set, and inserting the "delta" rows in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace one for 1, two for 2, and so on, then maybe this sql could work:

```
INSERT INTO PodMays
SELECT
  "Delta", A.A-B.A, A.B-B.B, A.C-B.C, A.D-B.D, A.E-B.E
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP 1
      * 
    FROM
      (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM PodMays WHERE Type <> "Delta" ORDER BY Type DESC)
    ORDER BY
      Type ASC
  ) AS A,
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 
      * 
    FROM 
      (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM PodMays WHERE Type <> "Delta" ORDER BY Type DESC)
    ORDER BY 
      Type DESC
  ) AS B
```